# Does IsNull work with varchar datatypes but not with text?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ado

I'm writing a VBA macro to copy tables from Excel into SQL, and I want the macro to skip writing a cell if that field in the database side already has data. I've been using the IsNull function and it works when the SQL field is varchar type, but it doesn't work (though doesn't give an error) when the SQL data type is text. I set a few of the SQL table columns as text because they contain full sentences that are more than the 50 characters allowed by the varchar data type.

Is there a better way to do this? I'm not working with a large or frequently updating data set so I thought individual null loop checks for each variable wouldn't be detectably bad for performance by the user.

```
If IsNull(.Fields("Field1").Value) Then 
   .Fields("Field1").Value = Range("Cell1").Value
   .Update
   .End If
```

Comment: `text` is a depreciated datatype - use `varchar(max)`

Comment: @DaleBurrell is correct text is depreciated, but if your table already contains that data type and you can not change it, try casing the `text` to `varchar(max)` in your SQL query.

Comment: I should have been more descriptive. The issue is that I'm trying to copy cells from the document header into the table 30 times; once for each record associated with 30 different experiment trials being performed. Most of the cells are writing to the table correctly for all 30 records, but with the longer text cells, they write correctly once, then the other 29 records remain blank for the associated fields. This happened when they were "text" datatype in the table, and still when they are "varchar(max)".

Comment: PS thanks for the help both of you!